# How to call same activity (same layout) with different data?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am new to android field. i am developing restaurant menu application, i have created list view which shows names of items in restaurant. when i select any one item in list view it will launch another activity, it contains text view field showing detail description of selected item. similarly when i select other items, it should launch same activity but data should be of that selected item, how to achieve this ? if i use sqlite database for data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the values onItemClick:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CalledActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(key, value);
        startActivity(intent);
```

If you want some data back from called Activity then you can use startActivityForResult() as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CalledActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(key, value);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

In called activity you can set data as:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Note: Here you set the value in intent and pass it to setResult().

On returning back to calling Activity you can get data by overriding:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //Get data from Intent "data" and do your task here....
        }
    }
```

Note: You can pass primitive data type values thru Intent and if you want to pass other types then you have to use Bundle like this.

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putIntArray(key, value);

//same way you can set other values.......
//Now set this Bundle value to Intent as you do for primitive type....

Intent intent = new Intent(context, CalledActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(data);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving data in Activity:

```
//For primitive values:
DataType var_name = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);

//For Bundle values:
Bundle var_name = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use intent extras to achieve this.
You can transfer data to your activity by using intent.putExtra("KEY", VALUE).
In the receiving activity you get the extras by calling getIntent().getExtras(); which returns a Bundle with the extras you've added in the calling activity.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the **extras** `Bundle` of an `Intent`, e.g.

Let's assume you have a `MenuListActivity` which shows the menu as list, and an `MenuItemActivity` which shows a single menu item in more detail.

In your `MenuListActivity.onListItemClick()` you want to pass the clicked menu item ID to your `MenuItemActivity`:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, final View view, int position, long id) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuItemActivity.class); // from -> to
    intent.putExtra(MenuItemActivity.ITEM_ID, id); // extra arguments: the menu item ID
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your `MenuItemActivity` you'll have a constant to identify the menu item (used above):

```
public static final String ITEM_ID = "item_id";

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    long menuItemId = extras.getLong(ITEM_ID);

    // fetch your menu item from database, using ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !! But i didn't understand the what dose id contain, which we r passing in intent.putExtra(). dose it contains long value of selected list row. if yes  then how this value will help for fetching data from database ?

Comment: When using a `CursorAdapter` to populate your `ListView`, you'll already have an ID column (e.g. primary key) in your SQLite database for this. `onListItemClick` passes in both `position` (which is rather useless for your use case) and `id` -- this is the same ID that you used with the `CursorAdapter` and in your SQLite database -- so it's perfect for looking up the menu item in your detail activity.

Comment: This is one of the reasons many Android database-related classes force you to provide an ID column based on `BaseColumns._ID` -- this way they always have a primary key to uniquely identify every record and can pass it back to your code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve.Suppose you want to send the position of the list view item which is clicked then on click method send id to the activity with the intent

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            //listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Intent i=new Intent(MyActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
          i.putExtras("position",""+position);
          startActivity(i);


        }
```

Similarly if you want to send data,have to work accordingly