# Android activities differing only in data they present

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an application. MainActivity has 50 buttons and all of them will open a new activity. Each of these  50 activities will look the same (it will have 4 buttons that open new activities). These new 4 activities will differ only in the fact they will have different information. Do I indeed need 200 activities (that will differ only in presenting different information to the user) and 200 layouts or is there a better way to do this? What's the proper way to do it?

I have managed to find this: [How to call same activity (same layout) with different data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305113/how-to-call-same-activity-same-layout-with-different-data)

The only problem is the data that I want to represent are: pictures, various texts and quiz questions from a database. So how can I send all of that data together?

Comment: no. you should learn more about intent and activities

Comment: Create some sort of model which identifies those 4 buttons for each screen and then use only one activity, and `switch` over the type to trigger action. But dude, what in the world are you even making? Is this one of those "A man bought 50 watermelons" thing?

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow that's a whole bunch of work. You can use Intents to move data within your app and reduce 200 Activities to 10 or less depending on what you're trying to do.